# Why data is not rendered on refresh in react js with asynchronous call?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am creating edit form.First i have to get data to edit form and i am calling it in **componentDidMount()**.Please see code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import CompanyForm from './CompanyForm';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { companyActions } from '../../../redux/actions/company-action';

class EditCompanyPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    };
    componentDidMount () {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(companyActions.getCompany(id));
    }
    render(){
        const {editUser } = this.props;
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Edit Company</h1>
                {
                    editUser && <CompanyForm handleActionParent={this.handleAction}  companyDataFP={editUser} />
                }   
            </div>
        );
    };
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { editUser } = state.companyReducer;

    return {
        editUser
    };
}

const EditCompany = connect(mapStateToProps)(EditCompanyPage);
export default EditCompany;
```

see code for CompanyForm component below:

```
import React from 'react';


class CompanyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            company :{
                name        : this.props.companyDataFP.name      || '',
                address1    : this.props.companyDataFP.address1  || '',
            }
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    };

    handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        newState.company[name] = value;
        this.setState(newState);
    }



    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    render(){

        return(
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.company.name} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label htmlFor="address1">Address 1</label>
                                <input type="text" name="address1" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.company.address1} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info" value="submit" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default CompanyForm;
```

It works fine when i access this form with

```
<Link to="/edit-form/:id" >Edit</Link>
```

but when i refresh the current page then values are not rendering into form to edit.
I am using redux approach for state management, please guide me i am new to react.

Comment: Probably you have installed Redux, but you are not using it, at least not in the code you've posted. It is hard to say what exactly is going on from this snipped.

Comment: i have mention i am using redux should i post all import file names? i asking question in generic term bro.

Comment: What info exactly does not load on refresh? The redux store is going to be reset to default. Your URL should stay the say, so the “id” value should get pulled into componentDidMount. What’s going wrong exactly?

Comment: I am calling action "companyActions.getCompany(id)" in componentDidMount after that i got editUser prop from redux store which i pass to child component and it works fine with Link(Route) but on refresh it rendered child component first and send editUser prop to child as empty then got editUser prop with data. @twils0

Comment: @hu7sy I think it’s going through a normal process when you refresh (component DID mount means the component is already mounted before this method is called; though sometimes, it updates quickly enough and you cannot tell). Are you saying you see a flash on refresh with editUser as empty, and you want to avoid this flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `ComponyForm` initializes form on its `componentDidMount` lifecycle function, so when `editUser` arrives nothing will change.

A way to handle this is changing:

```
<CompanyForm handleActionParent={this.handleAction}  companyDataFP={editUser}  />
```

to:

```
{editUser.name && <CompanyForm handleActionParent={this.handleAction}  companyDataFP={editUser}  />}
```

Comment: i already tried but it didn't work please see code again with your suggestion as well.

Comment: if in `companyReducer` you defined `editUser` as `{}` this code won't work, because editUser is not undefined and it's going through same flow as when there was no `editUser &&`, Check my edited answer.